# how can i order by index in postgres text search?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a search bar with autocomplete, I created a document column which computes the ts_vector of the `display name` column using the `simple` dictionary.

this is what I have in my document column now:

```
"'rami':1 'morgan':2"
"'serena':1 'william':2"
"'ferrel':2"
"'dicaprio':2 'ronald':1"
```

When performing query search, how can I rank the words by the first name, i.e. index 1, whereby querying the letter `r:*` will first return names that start with r and then second names that start with r.

so:

```
select displayname from celeb where document @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'r:*')
```

returns:

```
"'rami':1 'morgan':2"
"'dicaprio':1 'ronald':2"
"'ferrel':2"
"'serena':2 'william':1"
```

I know how to do ranking based on columns, but I couldn't find a way to do it based on an index of a specific column.

Comment: What is there to rank?  Either it starts with r, or it doesn't.

Comment: If you want to work with first names and last names separately, it seems like you should put them in two columns. What does using FTS get you here?

Comment: A little more context would be nice: table definition, index definition, Postgres version.

Answer (score 0):

Since `FALSE < TRUE`, you can use the prefix operator `^@` like this:

```
ORDER BY NOT first_name ^@ 'r', NOT second_name ^@ 'r'
```